# Sentinel configuration with NLog/log4net

Tags: log4net, nlog, sentinel

I have just started to use logging for my C# application. I am using NLog for logging entries to a *.log file and I view it using a Notepad++.

I want to try Sentinel, although I can view the logs on sentinel, I am not sure with the initial steps of sentinel, do I have to do the following every time I want to start sentinel to read a log?

1. Add new logger
2. Provider registration - NLog viewer
3. Visualizing the log

Cant I just start the sentinel and choose from a set configuration files ? If I am running two C# applications one using Log4Net and another Nlog, do I have to go through these over again instead of just selecting a config file?

Also what is the purpose of saving a session in sentinel ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a session saved in a file - file.sntl - you can instruct Sentinel to pull that session in on startup by supplying the filename on the command line.   I have nlog.sntl saved and use the following from a command script:

```
@echo off
start /B c:\apps\sentinel\sentinel nlog.sntl
```

I'm sure you'd be able to create a program shortcut with the same information - I just can't be bothered